Why would stop/starting IIS fix this Socket issue?
I have a Signalr web app that is using sockets to interact with a server application I can't control (nore have a source code / a protocol for). Each Signalr client sends a command to a Signalr Hub which sends opens a socket, sends a command to the server app then gets one or more responses back, which get sent back to the signalr client.
What I'm finding is that periodically (not clear on why) the server app stops sending responses back to the Signalr Hub. It does this when deployed and also when debugging locally. I'm creating a new Socket connection for each client command and closing it once we've received everything from the server app.
Stopping and starting the web app always fixes this, however given I'm not reusing socket connections I'm really not sure what's making this fix work. My thinking is that if I can understand that I can fix the cause.
public async Task SendCommand(string device, string? command)
{
        var ipendPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipaddress, port);
        var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
        {
            ReceiveTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds,
            SendTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).TotalMilliseconds,
        };
        await socket.ConnectAsync(ipendPoint);

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string? response = await SendCommandToServerAsync(socket, ipendPoint, device, command);
                command = null;
                if (response == null)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(2000);
                    continue;
                }

                if (response.Trim() != "GET&")
                { // If we're only sent a 'get' then don't update the client since there's no prompt
                    var parsedResponse = ParseResponse(response);
                    await Clients.Group(device).SendAsync("ReceiveResponse", device, parsedResponse);
                }

                if (response.Trim().EndsWith("GET&"))
                {
                    break;
                }

                await Task.Delay(2000);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (socket.Connected)
            {
                socket.Close();
            }
        }
}

private async Task<string?> SendCommandToServerAsync(Socket socket, IPEndPoint ipendPoint, string device, string? command)
{
    var responseSB = new StringBuilder();
    var debugSB = new StringBuilder();

    var text = device + "&" + command?.ToUpper() + "\r\n";
    var bRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text.ToString());

    debugSB.Append("request: " + text);

    string? result;
    try
    {
        if (command != null)
        {
            debugSB.AppendLine("Sent request");
            await socket.SendAsync(bRequest);
        }
        else
        {
            debugSB.AppendLine("Command is null");

        }
        await Task.Delay(900);
        byte[] array = new byte[8192];
        int num2 = 0;
        string text2;
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(300);
            if (!socket.Connected)
            {
                debugSB.AppendLine("Socket not connected");
                socket.Connect(ipendPoint);
            }

            int num3 = await socket.ReceiveAsync(array, SocketFlags.None);
            debugSB.AppendLine("Received " + num3.ToString() + " bytes");
            num2++;
            if (num3 > 0)
            {
                text2 = Encoding.Default.GetString(array, 0, num3);
                responseSB.AppendLine("Received: " + text2);
                string text3 = text2;
                text3 = text3.Replace("BEEP&" + '�', "");
                if (!(text3 == "") && text2.IndexOf('�') >= 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    _emailSender.SendEmail("george.duckett@aqualisa.co.uk", "AquaBar Info", "Got here with response: " + text2);
                }
            }
            else if (num2 == 20)
            {
                debugSB.AppendLine("Going to block_12");
                goto Block_12;
            }
        }

        debugSB.AppendLine("Out of while loop");

        string[] array2 = text2.Split(['�']);
        if (array2.Length > 2 && array2[0] == array2[1] && array2[0] != "BEEP&" && array2[0] != "PROMPT&")
        {
            text2 = array2[1];
        }
        return text2.Replace('�', ' ');
    Block_12:
        result = "Please Enter to Continue..GET&";

        _emailSender.SendEmail("george.duckett@aqualisa.co.uk", "AquaBar Info", "Got to Please enter with response: " + responseSB.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Debug: " + Environment.NewLine + debugSB.ToString());
    }
    catch (SocketException ex) when (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.TimedOut)
    {
        result = null;
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        result = null;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        result = "BEEP& ***Error***\n Server connection error.\n Please contact Administrator.";
    }
    return result;
}


How are you able to send multiple responses on the same request?  A request normally only gets one response.

Are you talking about a signalr response to the client, or are you talking about the servera app's response to my web app? If signalr I'm just sending multiple method calls to the client. If the server app, Are you saying that ReceiveAsync should only ever receive the entire response? My assumption was that sometimes a socket could receive some data, then receive some more data, if the server on the other end sent some data, waited then sent more data.

You appear to not have proper message framing. You may get part of a message in one read and part in another, you may get two messages in a single read. This is why you don't want to roll your own TCP messaging. Use an existing protocol such as HTTP to communicate with this server. Assuming you really do need to implement a full TCP protocol yourself, have a good read of https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html because there are many other pitfalls which you are not looking at: Nagle's algorithm/NoDelay, error handling, encoding, and what's with all those Task.Delay?

Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events

Are you running IIS on windows professional? it has a limit of max 10 concurrent connections.

What does stops sending responses mean? Is there any error message? You can try enabling logging to troubleshoot, add the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console package. Then, use the AddConsole method to configure the console logge. In addition, your problem occurs both locally and in IIS. You can also check which part of the error in this document matches your situatio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting

@AHoughton Did think that, but it's on windows server.

@jdweng What aspect specifically? I don't think the issue is the Signalr side of things since the command gets sent and received, there's just no reply from the app i'm sending data to (via the socket),

@Charlieface Ok, that makes sense. I can't change the protocol used by the app server unfortunately. Judging my the code (which is based on a client they had, hence all the Thread.Delays etc) I guess I'd be better off having a persistent socket opened and using the � character as the message terminator (which it seems to be).

@XudongPeng Stops sending responses means I send a command via the socket, but don't receive any response, where I normally would. I guess the app server got in some odd state somehow but what's confusing me is that I'm creating a new Socket for each command, and restarting the app pool/web server fixes the issue. If restarting fixes it, why would the issue persist through multiple new socket connections (with the exact same command sent). I thought, as far as the app is concerned whether we restart the app pool or not, each command is a fresh socket connection so behaviour should be the same.

Use from cmd.exe >Netstat -a to check status of connection.  See if connection closes or is stuck in a state.  You cannot have two connections with the same three parameters 1) Source IP 2) Destination IP 3) Port number

@jdweng Ahh, that makes sense about the one socket per source/dest/port. My issue now is if I protect that (either by making the socket persistent, or by introducing locks etc) I have single-threaded communication to the app server. Is there a way around this while not being able to change the app server's protocol?

Since there is no specific error message, have you tried adding logs as I mentioned above? That may help locate the problem.

Did you try to pool the Socket objects and reuse them? Database connections are pooled in the same manner and you can learn from that.
